# Iterating over custom data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data type that looks like this:

```
data Circle = Circle
        { radius                   :: Float
        , xPosition                :: Float
        , yPosition                :: Float
        }
```

I want to be able to write a scale function that can take a given circle and change its size like this:

```
aCircle = Circle 1.5 1 1
scaleFn aCircle 10
```

The desired output for this example with scale of 10 would be:

```
Circle 15 10 10
```

How can I create a function where I can iterate over each field and multiple the values by a constant? In my actual use case I need a way to map over all the fields as there are many of them.

Comment: You could write an instance of [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor), then `scale x = omap (* x)`. Or you could make your type into a functor (`data Circle_ a = Circle_ a a a deriving Functor`) and work with `type Circle = Circle Float`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson that's possible and commonly done, however I find such an approach rather unelegant. Such a functor instance isn't specific to the actual geometric properties of an object like `Circle`, but only to the _representation of these properties in a particular [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra))_.

Comment: BTW, note that non-strict `Float` fields [make little sense in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point) – they have worse precision than `Double`, but don't give any performance advantage because there's a pointer/thunk indirection. You probably want `Circle {radius, xPos, yPos :: !Float}`, then compiling with optimisations / with `-funbox-strict-fields` will represent `Circle` efficiently by just the plain float data as-is. (Indeed, `!Double` might be fine too, use that unless you've determined that `Float` really gives a significant memory/performance advantage.)

Answer (score 3):

*Scaling by a factor* is generally a [vector space operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). You could do the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.VectorSpace
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Circle = Circle
        { radius                   :: Float
        , xPosition                :: Float
        , yPosition                :: Float
        } deriving (Generic, Show)

instance AdditiveGroup Circle
instance VectorSpace Circle where
  type Scalar Circle = Float

main = print $ Circle 1.5 1 1 ^* 10
```

(result: `Circle {radius = 15.0, xPosition = 10.0, yPosition = 10.0}`).

(requires [`vector-space >= 0.11`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.11), which has just [added support for generic-derived instances](https://github.com/conal/vector-space/commit/3a5c3d59d310776e90a70fba75e7242233f9701c).)

However I should remark that `Circle` as such is **not** really a good `VectorSpace` instance: adding two circles doesn't make any sense, and scaling by a negative factor gives a bogus radius. Only define such an instance if your real use case follows the actual [vector space axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

What you really want for a type like `Circle` is something like [`diagrams`' `Transformable` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-core-1.4.0.1/docs/Diagrams-Core-Transform.html#t:Transformable). But I don't think there's any automatic way to derive an instance for that. In fact, since `diagrams` has – unfortunately IMO – switched from `vector-space` to `linear`, something like this has become considerably tougher to do even in principle.

Comment: That has to be the strangest instance of vectorspace I have ever seen, where scaling changes the position of an object. I like it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use "scrap your boilerplate":

```
import Data.Generics

data Circle = Circle
    { radius                   :: Float
    , xPosition                :: Float
    , yPosition                :: Float
    }
    deriving (Show, Data)

circleModify :: (Float -> Float) -> Circle -> Circle
circleModify f = gmapT (mkT f)
```

Intuitively, above, `mkT f` transforms `f` into a function which is applicable to any type: if the argument of `mkT f` is a `Float`, then `f` is applied, otherwise the argument is returned as it is.
The newly constructed general function is called a "transformation": the `T` in `mkT` stands for that.

Then, `gmapT` applies the transformation `mkT f` to all the fields of the circle. Note that is a field contained, say, `(Float, Bool)` that float would be unaffected. Use `everywhere` instead of `gmapT` to recursively go deeper.

Note that I'm not a big fan of this approach. If for any reason you change the type of a field, that change will not trigger a type error but `gmapT (mkT ...)` will now simply skip over that field.

Generic programming can be convenient, but sometimes a bit too much, in that type errors can be silently transformed into unexpected results at runtime. Use with care.

Comment: If all fields really have the same type, and you want to express that as a type-checked condition, you could use `generics-sop` instead and write `circleModify f = to . hcmap (Proxy @((~) Float)) (mapII f) . from`.